# Fast cold start text editor

Tags: c#, ide, text-editor

Is there text editor with c# syntax highlight which starts VERY FAST? I just want look source code some files in project and i donnt want wait 30 seconds while VS starts.

Comment: `ed`, the official Unix editor, starts up fast.

Comment: @mathepic, but doesn't have C# syntax highlighting.

Comment: nothing that can be solved by throwing more hardware at the problem. I have loads of extensions installed and my VS starts in under 10s, with solution loaded. GET A SSD!

Comment: @Johannes 10 seconds? You consider that _fast_?

Comment: @mathepic: Sure enough, I do also use Notepad++ for quick things ^^ But for code _browsing_ there's nothing that beats VS + CodeRush for me.

Comment: Since nobody has suggested it, Sublime Text is a good one, though version 2 is a little slow to start the first time you run it (per boot). Version 3 is a lot better, but it's in beta for paying customers only at the moment.

Comment: I would say lpe. Everything else here except ed (which is too hard to use) is slow. If you need _very fast_ I assume you need something belov 0,5s.

Answer (score 23):

I'd suggest [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

- easy to use (integration into Explorer context menu)
- highly flexible, lots of addons available
- open source (free as in both "free speech" and "free beer")

Comment: There's [Vim for windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc), it starts even faster than Npp, I guess.

Answer (score 14):

Vim starts faster than just about anything (anything sophisticated enough to have syntax highlighting anyway) and ships with C# syntax highlighting.  As you're probably already aware though, the learning curve is steep. [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org/)

Comment: There's a nice quick reference card in various formats here: http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vim.html

Comment: Also when getting started, be sure to run the `vimtutor` command.

Comment: +1 Nothing better then Vim

Comment: If you're a Windows user and new to vim, you might want to try the [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) config for vim. Also, as you get to use vim more, you may want to add some [integration with Visual Studio](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio).

Comment: I'm a vim user, but seldom use vim for "quick looking" because vim is slow. Look at lpe and you get a feeling for speed. To start an empty file and then close vim again takes 0,4 s for me, with lpe it takes 0,1 s. It's not uncommon for vim to be above 0,5s in startup time, and everything above 0,5 s is slow. You really should have that high expectations.

Comment: @iveqy This was a suggestion alternative to _a full graphical IDE_ which is 2 orders of magnitude slower than Vim.  Fully loaded with plugins my Vim config will load most files in about 400ms.  A bare configuration for me is closer to ~150ms. I have no doubt that lpe (which doesn't appear to have been updated since 2000) is fast, but would have kind of a high barrier to entry for a Windows user as the OP was.

Comment: @Michael you're completely right. I just me beeing a bit sad about people thinking slow things are fast just because they are used to really slow things.

Answer (score 2):

Related: I think the trick is to do your development using two editors. When you have VS with Resharper or other analysis add-ons it becomes very slow, but also very useful. So when you go to crank out code the VS environment is more like quicksand than anything else.

So, the plan is, get yourself a generic editor, generic but extensible. Learn that extensibility and enhance that editor over the years, for it will be your 'home base' editor. I use SlickEdit.

Once you have your generic editor, you should be able to program them to do a line, col, file jump from one to the other. The jump into VS is not easy though, you will have to make an exe that uses COM to control the running instance of the IDE.

if you google "VSGoto slickedit" you will find a version of that exe, but it tends to fail intermittently.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Editplus** editor.. it is very very fast

you can download it from
http://www.editplus.com/download.html

For free open source editor, you can try **Notepad++**

you can download it from 
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/

Comment: It's not free, if that is relevant.